# construction of line segment of a length $\sqrt{a^2-b^2+c^2+d^2}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

There are line segments $a, b, c, d$ and $a > b$. I have a  question how to construct a line segment of a length $\sqrt{a^2-b^2+c^2+d^2}$.  I can use Pythagoras theorem but I don't know how to make use of it.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a first right triangle with legs $a$ and $c$, then a second having as a first leg the hypotenuse of the first triangle, and a second leg of length $d$. Finally, draw a third triangle having the same hypotenuse as the second one and a leg equal to $b$. The length of the other leg is your answer.

[image]

Comment: For the final construction, draw a semicircle on the hypotenuse and then an arc centered on the end of the hypotenuse of length b. Where this arc intersects the semicircle is the corner of this last right triangle.

Comment: please, can you show it with image of a construction?